# Python email "from name" customization

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a python script to send email and it works just fine but the problem is when I check my email inbox.
[image]

I want that username to be customize username and not the whole email address.

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text, *post the actual text* as well as what you have tried researched. I've also removed the django tag since this doesn't look like how django sends messages so I assume its pyramid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add sender name before sender address in python email script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107983/how-to-add-sender-name-before-sender-address-in-python-email-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format you should use for the from address is:

```
Your Name <username@domain.com>
```

Comment: in your `fromaddr` variable

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multipart message, and render markdown, if you want beautiful messages.

[image]

```py
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

multipart_msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

multipart_msg["Subject"] = message.splitlines()[0]
multipart_msg["From"] = DISPLAY_NAME + f' <{SENDER_EMAIL}>'
multipart_msg["To"] = receiver

text = message
html = markdown.markdown(text)

part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

multipart_msg.attach(part1)
multipart_msg.attach(part2)

server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, receiver,
                            multipart_msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this code at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Email

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
fromaddr = "youremailid@gmail.com"
toaddr = "target@example.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = ""
body = "This is just a test email. Do not reply to this"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("youremailusername", "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

Format for from address is
`username@server.com`
Format for to address is
`username@server.com`
and `smtplib.SMTP` accepts 0 or 2 parameters.
The first parameter is type `str` and the second parameter is type `int`