# How to add sender name before sender address in python email script

Tags: python, email, smtp

Here's my code

```
# Import smtplib to provide email functions
import smtplib
 
# Import the email modules
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 
# Define email addresses to use
addr_to   = 'user@outlook.com'
addr_from = 'user@aol.com'
 
# Define SMTP email server details
smtp_server = 'smtp.aol.com'
smtp_user   = 'user@aol.com'
smtp_pass   = 'pass'
 
# Construct email
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['To'] = addr_to
msg['From'] = addr_from
msg['Subject'] = 'test test test!'
 
# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "This is a test message.\nText and html."
html = """\

"""
 
# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
 
# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
 
# Send the message via an SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I just want the email received to display the sender name before sender email address like this : [sender_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDEXx.jpg)

Comment: @tripleee FYI, it was taken from Python's official [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id5).

Comment: @Leponzo Thanks for the pointer! I have removed the comment as it was basically just incorrect.

Answer (score 44):

In the year 2020 and Python 3, you do things like this:

```py
from email.utils import formataddr
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = formataddr(('Example Sender Name', 'john@example.com'))
msg['To'] = formataddr(('Example Recipient Name', 'jack@example.org'))
msg.set_content('Lorem Ipsum')

with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 14):

It depends on whether the "friendly name" is basic ASCII or requires special characters.

Basic example:

```
msg['From'] = str(Header('Magnus Eisengrim <meisen99@gmail.com>'))
```

If you need to use non US-ASCII characters, it's more complex, but the attached article should help, it is very thorough:  http://blog.magiksys.net/generate-and-send-mail-with-python-tutorial

Comment: That will change the receiver name!!

Comment: Updated the answer, but the same logic applies to the "From" header as well as the "To" header.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question - however, I faced the same problem and came up with the following:

`msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header('Someone Somewhere', 'utf-8')), 'xxxxx@gmail.com'))`

You'll need to import `from email.header import Header` and `from email.utils import formataddr`.

That would make only the sender name appear on the inbox, without the `<xxxxx@gmail.com>`:
[image]

While the email body would include the full pattern:
[image]

Putting the sender name and the email in one string (`Sender Name <sender@server.com>`) would make some email clients show the it accordingly on the receiver's inbox (unlike the first picture, showing only the name).

Comment: As a non-english user, this works.

Answer (score 8):

I took the built-in example and made it with this:

```
mail_body = "the email body"
mailing_list = ["user1@company.com"]
msg = MIMEText(mail_body)

me = 'John Cena <mail@company.com>'
you = mailing_list
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = mailing_list

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that if I send an email with gmail and set the `From` header to `sender name <email@gmail.com>`, the email arrives with the `From` like:

> **From** sender name email@gmail.com email@gmail.com.

So I guess at least with gmail you should set the `From` header like as follow:

```
msg['From'] = "sender name"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use below mentioned code, you just need to change sender and receiver with user name and password, it will work for you.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'xyz@gmail.com'
receivers = ['abc@gmail.com']

message = """From: sender_name <xyz@gmail.com>
To: reciever_name <abc@gmail.com>
Subject: sample test mail

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp_server',port)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message) 
   smtpObj.login(user,password)        
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except:
   print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

for more detail please visit https://www.datadivein.com/2018/03/how-to-auto-send-mail-using-python.html

Comment: Replacing a perfectly good MIME message with a hard-coded hand-constructed message is not a step in the right direction.